# How to use Basic HTTP Django Authorization middleware?

Tags: django

I don't understand the django middleware snippet here: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1304/

I have incorporated the middleware correctly, and upon visiting my site, I can manually enter in the username and password and authenticate. My problem is that I don't know how to send a request from Postman/curl to authenticate. I have included an "Authorization" header in my Postman request, but I don't know how to format the values.

For example: "Authorization: user password"

```
    def __call__(self, request):
    if 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' not in request.META:
        return self._unauthed()
    else:
        authentication = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']
        (auth_method, auth) = authentication.split(' ', 1)
        if 'basic' != auth_method.lower():
            return self._unauthed()
        auth = base64.b64decode(auth.strip()).decode('utf-8')
        username, password = auth.split(':', 1)
        if (
            username == settings.BASICAUTH_USERNAME and
            password == settings.BASICAUTH_PASSWORD
        ):
            return self.get_response(request)

        return self._unauthed()
```

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks. Can you post it as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For curl, `curl -H "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n admin:123456 | base64)" https://example.com/api/endpoint/`

In Postman, there is an authorization tab under the url, you can basic auth as type and enter username and password, postman will base64 encode it and add to headers.

[image]